# How to find and close properly to those json which are not closed properly

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json file which looks like this

```
   [
    {
      "ID" : 230110850,
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "s1" : [ 22.226, 60.4 ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "timestamp" : 54,
      }
    {
      "ID" : 265527480,
      "type" : "Feature",
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
         "s1" : [ 22.2, 60.432 ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "timestamp" : 54,
      }
]
```

I have like around million of lines like this but some of the elements of json are not closed properly.

What I am trying to do is find `'}'` and if I Find then go to nextline and if `nextline == '{',` then I want to replace that line with `'}, {'`.

Here is my code but it is not working correctly.

```
lst = []

with open('a.txt', 'r') as f1: # a.txt contains those files
    for line in f1:
        if '}' is line:
            line = next(f1)
            if '{' is line:
                lst.append(line.replace('{', '}, {'))

        else:
            lst.append(line)
```

This is giving me an error for that next line loop.

```
StopIteration
```

plus this code is going to very slow as it has to check each and everyline.

is there a better solution for this ( perhaps using regex multiline). Any advice, suggestions would be great.

Comment: `if '{' is line` => you mean :`if '{' in line`

Comment: Oh dear, This is a nightmare. I feel your pain. (ps. you shouldn't try to go around the file handler's normal iteration inside the for loop. Your issue is arising probably because you're calling `next(f1)` and it may be the end of file when you try to call that manually.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I want to use only is or == otherwise its going to mess with others too as it possible there are { and } contains in next line

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, this is giving me really Pain ( True). If you have any idea how to do. Please.

Comment: you have other issues : `        "type" : "Point",` that doesn't work you cannot end a list with `,`

Comment: problem is that `line` contains a linefeed, it won't be equal to `}`, never

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre there are datas, which I don't want to share for some other reasons. only problem is some of the json elements are not closed properly.....

Comment: so [edit] your question to only show issues, not extra issues.

Comment: Now, heres the real kicker. Are only SOME of them wrong or are all jsons messed up in this specific manner? (to be more specific, all jsons closing with a `}` have an issue)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, problem is only some couple of thousands of them doesn't close properly. and there are over millions of lines and its hard to tell which one are messy one and they all are in the middle.

Comment: In that case, whatever solution we may propose may ruin something else unexpectedly. It might not be possible to brute force your way out of this one. For example, any code that fixes an invalid bracket would ruin an already-correct bracket.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh probably I can use regex multiline solution for example in notepad++, visualcode or even python ? All I need is to find '} ' and if the next line contains only '{' then replace last line with '}, {'. Any idea on those ?

Comment: In your example, the indentation is an indication of the depth. Can we rely on it on your true data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps, but your mileage may vary. [Explanation link](https://regex101.com/r/lwsUIj/1)
I tried to keep some of the formatting intact to hopefully make it easier to find potential issues, i suspect there may be some. The general idea is i read the file in one go, and try to match across two lines for '} {' and make the changes accordingly.

```
import re

with open('a.txt', 'r') as f1:
    content = f1.read()

result = re.sub(r'}\n(\s*){', r'}\n\1},\n\1{', content)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know :)